# How to put data from firebase to variable android?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin-coroutines

```
fun getUnReadMessages(roomId: Int, userId: Int): Int {

    var counter: Int = 0
        database.getReference("/Conversations/").child(roomId.toString()).child("messages")
            .addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    for (i in 0 until snapshot.childrenCount) {
                        val isRead =
                            snapshot.child(i.toString()).child("is_read")
                                .getValue(Boolean::class.java)

                        val senderId =
                            snapshot.child(i.toString()).child("senderid")
                                .getValue(Int::class.java)

                        if (senderId != userId && isRead == false) {
                            counter++
                        }
                    }
                    Log.i(TAG, counter.toString())
                }

                override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                    TODO("Not yet implemented")
                }

            })

    return counter
}
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to show where you are stuck ? What's not working ?

Comment: Firebase calls are asynchronous, so you can't return a value set within the callback (your function will return immediately, but the callback runs some time in the future). Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value) for different examples of how to deal with that.

Comment: Since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-firebase-realtime-database-using-get-269ef3e179c5) with the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/RealtimeDatabase) will help.